# DIV content not parsed as HTML

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am using VS2015, C#, MVC project.

I've created a [custom calendar](http://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/KrLzkW). When typing the note, it's correctly shown to the user as html (breaks, bold, italic ... - everything works fine).
If I try to update calendar (each DIVs content gets pulled from database) then DIVs content is no longer displayed as html but as plain text.

Why is that so?

I am parsing DIVs content with this code (@noteCurrentDate is DIVs content):

```
 <div id="divDays" class="divDays">


            @{
                DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Model.StartEndDateTable[0]["StartDate"]).Date;
                DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Model.StartEndDateTable[0]["EndDate"]).Date;

                DateTime tempDate = startDate;

                while (tempDate <= endDate)
                {
                    DL.DataSets.Notes.spSelectNotesRow result = Model.NotesTable.AsEnumerable().Where(myRow => myRow.DateNote.Date == tempDate).FirstOrDefault();
                    string noteCurrentDate = "";
                    string activeDate = tempDate.Date.Month == Model.CurrentMonth ? "" : "dayUnactive";
                    string dateID = tempDate.Date.Day.ToString("d2") + "_" + tempDate.Date.Month.ToString("d2") + "_" + tempDate.Date.Year;

                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        noteCurrentDate = result.Note;
                    }

                    <div class="divDay">
                        <div class="divInnerDay">
                             <span id="spanDayNumber" class="spanDayNumber unselectable @activeDate">@tempDate.Date.Day</span>
                             <div id="@dateID" class="content editable" ng-keyup="updateNote('@dateID')">@noteCurrentDate</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                                                

                    tempDate = tempDate.AddDays(1);
                }
            }
        </div>
        <!-- divDays -->
```

When typing into field the content is shown like this:

[image]

Content is being saved on each key-up event to database:

```
<b>Text in bold</b><div><i>text in italic (one break before)</i></div><div><i><u>text underline (another break)</u></i></div>
```

So, html is correctly saved in database. But, when the page is refreshed, DIVs content is shown like this:

[image]

And here's the source. For me, it looks correct html. Why it is not parsed as html but as plain text?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `@Html.Raw()` for your content